# On/at with morning/afternoon/evening/night

Tags: grammar, prepositions, articles, time, dates

I have a sentence:

Happiness is drinking a glass of champagne **on a hot summer afternoon**.

So I'm thinking if we want to say the same about night do we have **at night** or **on [article] night**?

I know we say **in (the afternoon / the evening / the night)** when we mean 'during this period of time'. Correct?

But what is the difference between **on** and **at**? Could we use articles with **on\at** and **night**?

Comment: _At night_ means 'during the hours of darkness', but if you describe the night (in this case, probably meaning _evening_), you need _on_. The folk song 'The Lincolnshire Poacher' has the line 'It's my delight on a shiny night in the season of the year." (I assume _shiny_ means _moonlit_.)

Comment: @Astralbee Thanks, it almost answers but I don't see there a lot about *on* preposition (like in my example sentence). Could we use *on* with night? Why do we use *on* with afternoon but not *at*?

Comment: @DariaPydorenko We don't - we'd normally say "**in** the afternoon". The accepted answer I linked you to says this.

Comment: @Astralbee _In the afternoon_, but _on a fine afternoon_ or _on a moonlit night_.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks! Does it works like that: I usually sleep in the evening / I usually sleep on a rainy evening. (are articles correct too?)

Comment: Yes, those are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've investigated my question. As I understand it works like that:

> I could do it in the morning
>
> I could do it tomorrow morning.
>
> I could do it in a morning. *(about any morning, not commonly used)*
>
> I could do it in the mornings. *(about every morning)*
>
> I could do it on a lovely morning. *('on' because of an adjective)*

And with 'night':

> I could do it at night.
>
> I could do it on a lovely night. *('on' because of an adjective)*
>
> I could do it if I awake in the night. *(something poetic, about this night)*

Good examples here:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time

Please, correct me if I understand something wrong.